# Loading real world XML problems in OptaPlanner 6.1.0

Tags: java, drools, optaplanner

I've been studying the OptaPlanner framwork for a bit and have found the CloudBalancingHelloWorld  example fits a problem I'm tasked with fairly well - only it loads a fake generated problem set and I'd like to create my own XML file and load that instead ... but the docs seem a bit sparse on this subject, and I don't see any examples.

The existing code in CloudBalancingHellowWorld.java is:

```
// Load a problem with 400 computers and 1200 processes
// This gets replaced with a class that loads a *real* problem - from a DB for example.
CloudBalance unsolvedCloudBalance = new CloudBalancingGenerator().createCloudBalance(400, 1200);
```

And I'd like to be able to programmatically load an XML problem description. Are there any examples out there of this being done or Docs to be perused to gain some inspiration?

Answer (score 1):

The whole dataset serialization from and to XML is part of optaplanner-examples: OptaPlanner itself doesn't provide or require any serialization format. That being said, optaplanner-examples includes the following serialization formats:

- Every example: [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) XML format in `data` directories `unsolved` and `solved`. The format is defined by the XStream annotations (`@XStreamAlias` etc) on the domain classes. In some cases the XML format is too verbose, causing `OutOfMemoryError`, for example for the big `MachineReassignment` B datasets.
- Most examples: Competition specific TXT format in `data` directories `import` and `export`. The format is defined by the competition (see docs). In the examples GUI, click on button Import to load them.

Comment: Geoffrey - In the examples GUI - I can load the XML problem files well enough. What I want is to find the specific code that reads that specific XML file in when I load it. Locating that is the nontrival task. Once I have that I can port it to the HelloWorld Format and use it there - which is my current goal.

Comment: Take a look at `SolutionDao` and `XStreamSolutionDao` in optaplanner-examples

Comment: I just found those in the file SolutionBusiness.Java a hour before you typed your reply. I'll experiment with those and report back if I run into trouble.

Comment: I found those but instead of me writing from scratch file I/O support using import java.io.File, the good folks at OptaPlanner probably have something under the hood, don't they? What would that be? Here is my read line for the problem file set: 
CloudBalance unsolvedCloudBalance = (CloudBalance) solutionDao.readSolution(file);

The question is how does one get "file" from OptaPlanner?