# How to store the fetched MySQL data into Optaplanner-examples

Tags: java, xml, jboss, redhat, optaplanner

I have created a MySQL database with entries similar to nurse roster, i have generated these entries to be in XML format using below code.

```html
package com.jdbcxml;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;



class EmployeeDAO
{
    private Connection conn = null;
    
    static
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public EmployeeDAO()
    {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://50.62.23.184:3306/dbname";
        String userId = "root";
        String passWord = "";
        try
        {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userId, passWord);
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public void finalize()
    {
        try
        {
            conn.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Document getCustomerList()
    {
        Document doc = null;

        try
        {
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * from t7_users");

            doc = JDBCUtil.toDocument(rs);   

            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return doc;
    }
    
 public String getCustomerListAsString()
 {
  String xml = null;

  try
  {
   Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
   ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * from t7_users");

            xml = JDBCUtil.toXML(rs);

   rs.close();
   stmt.close();
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

  return xml;
 }  
   
    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
    { 
        EmployeeDAO dao = new EmployeeDAO(); 
        
  String xml = dao.getCustomerListAsString();
  System.out.println(xml);
  
        Document doc = dao.getCustomerList();
        System.out.println(doc);
        //PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt"));
        //out.write(doc);;
        //out.close();
        
        
    }
}
```

Now i need this data to be saved in Optaplanner-examples-->data-->nurserostering-->unsolved folder.

Also after doing this will the optaplanner be able to write a solution to the passed data to some file so that i can display those results on my webpage.

Comment: This is not an OptaPlanner question, but a hibernate and JPA question. Tag and name the title appropriately to get a better answer.

Comment: thank you and i apologies for it

Answer (score 0):

Why you storing the data you get from database to xml file? It will be more efficiently feed the data to optaplanner solver and get the best solution. Read my answer from your previous question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26750205/how-do-i-load-a-xml-in-optaplanner/26773821#26773821)